# insert function executed twice

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

i am trying to build a blog using vanilla js and Firebase everything is working fine my problem is I have an insert function that is responsible for inserting the data and uploading it to my Firebase the problem that I am facing is that the data is inserted twice

this is my function

```
const entriesRef = ref(db, "all/people");
let listener; // Declare the listener variable outside the function

function insertData() {
  const enterTitle = document.getElementById("enterTitle");
  const enterContent = document.getElementById("enterContent");
  const enterImage = document.getElementById("enterImage");

  // Get the entered values
  const titleValue = enterTitle.value;
  const contentValue = enterContent.value;
  const imageFile = enterImage.files[0];

  let isDataInserted = false; // Flag variable to track successful data insertion

  if (listener) {
    off( listener); // Remove the existing listener if it exists
  }

  listener = onValue(entriesRef, (snapshot) => {
    // Check if data has already been inserted
    if (isDataInserted) {
      return; // Exit the listener if data has been inserted
    }

    const lastEntry = snapshot.val();

    let newEntryKey = "01";

    if (lastEntry !== null) {
      const keys = Object.keys(lastEntry);
      const lastEntryKey = keys[keys.length - 1];
      const lastEntryNumber = parseInt(lastEntryKey);
      const nextNumber = lastEntryNumber + 1;
      newEntryKey = nextNumber.toString().padStart(2, "0");
    }

    const storage = getStorage(app);
    const storageRef = sRef(storage, `images/${newEntryKey}`);

    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, imageFile);
    uploadTask
      .then((snapshot) => {
        getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)
          .then((downloadURL) => {
            return set(ref(db, `all/people/${newEntryKey}`), {
              ID: newEntryKey,
              Title: titleValue,
              Content: contentValue,
              ImageURL: downloadURL,
            });
          })
          .then(() => {
            // Once the data is inserted successfully, set the flag and remove the listener
            isDataInserted = true;
            alert("Data successfully inserted");
            off(entriesRef, "value", listener); // Remove the listener

            // Reset the input fields
            enterTitle.value = "";
            enterContent.value = "";
            enterImage.value = "";
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors that occur during the upload or data insertion
        console.error("Error inserting data:", error);
        // You can add additional error handling or display a message to the user
      });
  });
}
```

i have tried to add a boolean that stopped the insert to check if the data was inserted or not so I can use the off function but it's not working

Comment: i have added a Location.reload after the alert to fix the problem 
but this is not a good solution to solve the problem so kindly plz if anyone knows the problem advise me 

          .then(() => {
            isDataInserted = true;
            alert("Data successfully inserted");
            location.reload();
            off(entriesRef); // Remove the listener
            return
            // Reset the input fields
            enterTitle.value = "";
            enterContent.value = "";
            enterImage.value = "";
          });